# How to have two logins/Authentication policies within same app?

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid

I have a standard Pyramid application. In the `__init__.py` main method, I have a `config.add_request_method(AuthHelper.get_user, 'user', reify=True)` to set up a globally accessible user object.

I store all users in a `user` table, and I access the current, logged-in user via the `self.request.user`. My problem is that I would like to create an admin portal, completely separate from the rest of the application, and I would like those "admins" to be stored in a table called `admin`. These admins are not users – they have a separate login page, and should have no relation to the user table.

I am having trouble setting up  Authorization for admins. For instance, in the `remember(self.request, admin.id, max_age=...` there is no way to differentiate between a successfully logged in user vs. a successfully logged in admin, as far as the authentication goes. A `User.id = 1` could access the admin portal for an `Admin.id == 1`, even though they logged in with different credentials on different views.

I thought about using an `Admin.username` in the `remember` method, but it still clashes with the `config.add_request_method(AuthHelper.get_user...)` (understandably so), which takes a `User.id`.

How can I set up an Authorization policy such that if you logged in successfully from the Admin portal login, your authorization is separate from a regular user who logged in from the main index page, and vice versa?

I feel like this is a relatively basic need, so I must be missing a simple way to implement this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an "admin portal, completely separate from the rest of the application" one option would be to set up a separate WSGI application, which would have a separate `request` object, authentication policy etc.

Then you can assemble two applications together with a [WSGI "composite"](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#composite-applications) so your "normal" application is mounted on `/` and your admin is on, say, `/admin`.

You can still import the same code (models and even views) from your admin app - basically it's a matter of adding another "startup" file (the one which contains `return config.make_wsgi_app()`) and configuring the `.ini` file.

If you change the cookie name in the admin app you'll be even able to be logged in as a User in your "main" app and as an Admin in your "admin portal":

```
authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
    ...
    cookie_name='admin_auth_tkt',
    ...)
authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)
```

You'll need to define an *entry point* in your `setup.py` file:

```
  entry_points="""\
      [paste.app_factory]
      main = MyApp:main_app
      admin = MyApp:admin_app
  """
```

( `main_app` and `admin_app` should be functions importable from `myapp`, which return respective WSGI applications).

Then you can assemble a composite:

```
[composite:main]
use = egg:Paste#urlmap
/ = mainapp
/files = adminapp

[app:mainapp]
use = egg:MyApp#main

[app:adminapp]
use = egg:MyApp#admin
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Question: For the new start-up file, how does the .ini composite app know to look for my new startup file called say: init_admin.py? My main app file is by default called __init__.py, which gets run on startup (needless to say), but if my new file is called something different, where do "link" it with the additional app in my .ini file?

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit